# Test data giving prediction error in Keras in the model with Embedding layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, word-embedding

I have trained a Bi-LSTM model to find NER on a set of sentences. For this I took the different words present and I did a mapping between a word and a number and then created the Bi-LSTM model using those numbers. I then create and pickle that model object.

Now I get a set of new sentences containing certain words that the training model has not seen. Thus these words do not have a numeric value till now. Thus when I test it on my previously existing model, it would give an error. It is not able to find the words or features as the numeric values for those do not exist.

To circumvent this error I gave a new integer value to all the new words that I see.

However, when I load the model and test it, it gives the error that:

```
InvalidArgumentError: indices[0,24] = 5444 is not in [0, 5442)   [[Node: embedding_14_16/Gather = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT32, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, validate_indices=true,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](embedding_14_16/embeddings/read, embedding_14_16/Cast)]]
```

The training data contains 5445 words including the padding word. Thus = [0, 5444]

5444 is the index value I have given to the paddings in the test sentences. Not clear why it is assuming the index values to range between [0, 5442).

I have used the base code available on the following link: https://www.kaggle.com/gagandeep16/ner-using-bidirectional-lstm

The code:

```
input = Input(shape=(max_len,))
model = Embedding(input_dim=n_words, output_dim=50
                  , input_length=max_len)(input)

model = Dropout(0.1)(model)
model = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=100, return_sequences=True, recurrent_dropout=0.1))(model)
out = TimeDistributed(Dense(n_tags, activation="softmax"))(model)  # softmax output layer

model = Model(input, out)
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

#number of  epochs - Also for output file naming
epoch_num=20
domain="../data/Laptop_Prediction_Corrected"
output_file_name=domain+"_E"+str(epoch_num)+".xlsx"

model_name="../models/Laptop_Prediction_Corrected"
output_model_filename=model_name+"_E"+str(epoch_num)+".sav"


history = model.fit(X_tr, np.array(y_tr), batch_size=32, epochs=epoch_num, validation_split=0.1, verbose=1)
```

`max_len` is the total number of words in a sentence and `n_words` is the vocab size. In the model the padding has been done using the following code where `n_words=5441`:

```
X = pad_sequences(maxlen=max_len, sequences=X, padding="post", value=n_words)
```

The padding in the new dataset:

```
max_len = 50
# this is to pad sentences to the maximum length possible
#-> so all records of X will be of the same length

#X = pad_sequences(maxlen=max_len, sequences=X, padding="post", value=res_new_word2idx["pad_blank"])

#X = pad_sequences(maxlen=max_len, sequences=X, padding="post", value=5441)
```

Not sure which of these paddings is correct?

However, the vocab only includes the words in the training data. When I say:

```
p = loaded_model.predict(X)
```

How to use `predict` for text sentences which contain words that are not present in the initial vocab?

Comment: What value you used for the first argument of Embedding layer, i.e. `Embedding(?, ...)`? That's the vocab size.

Comment: @today thanks for the response. Have provided update and also the code. I think my problem is that how does the code handle words in the test data that are not part of the vocab to number mapping?

Comment: Yes. It seems that when defining the model you have set the vocab size to 5442, i.e. `n_words == 5442`. However, in inference time you have a word with index greater than or equal to 5442. This is called out-of-vocabulary (i.e. oov) word. There are various methods to handle them. One simple approach is to just ignore them. Another one is to consider a reserved index for these words in the embedding layer, so the vocab size would be 5443.

Comment: @today thank you for your response. I defined a word as "newword". Assigned it an index number and preprocessed to give all new  words the same index. However I am still getting the same error. Is it because the padding in the new data is becoming different? Have updated the code to reflect the same.

Comment: I think the problem is that `n_words` is still set to 5442 whereas the total number of words must be 5445.

Comment: @today I am still not able to get it. In the training dataset there are 5441 words. The pad sequence number is kept as 5442.
In the test data as well, have kept the pad sequence number the same i.e. 5442. Is there a way in which I can ignore all the new words in the new dataset?

Comment: What happened? Could you resolve the issue? Did you read my answer?

Comment: @today thank you for the answer and the followup. I am still in the process implementing the answer based on this tokenization approach. I shall get back with the results. Thank you again for the guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Keras [`Tokenizer`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/text/#tokenizer) class and its methods to easily tokenize and preprocess the input data. Specify the vocab size when instantiating it and then use its `fit_on_texts()` method on the training data to construct a vocabulary based on the given texts. After that you can use its `text_to_sequences()` method to convert each text string to a list of word indices. The good thing is that only the words in the vocabulary is considered and all the other words are ignored (you can set those words to one by passing `oov_token=1` to `Tokenizer` class):

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer

# set num_words to limit the vocabulary to the most frequent words
tok = Tokenizer(num_words=n_words)

# you can also pass an arbitrary token as `oov_token` argument 
# which will represent out-of-vocabulary words and its index would be 1
# tok = Tokenizer(num_words=n_words, oov_token='[unk]')

tok.fit_on_texts(X_train)

X_train = tok.text_to_sequences(X_train)
X_test = tok.text_to_sequences(X_test)  # use the same vocab to convert test data to sequences
```

You can optionally use `pad_sequences` function to pad them with zeros or truncate them to make them all have the same length:

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

X_train = pad_sequences(X_train, maxlen=max_len)
X_test = pad_sequences(X_test, maxlen=max_len)
```

Now, the vocab size would be equal to `n_words+1` if you have not used oov token or `n_words+2` if you have used it. And then you can pass the correct number to embedding layer as its `input_dim` argument (first positional argument):

```
Embedding(correct_num_words, embd_size, ...)
```

Comment: Thank you for all the support and direction given in solving this problem. Using the Tokenizer the problem is resolved. Really appreciate it.